# Apache Tomcat 8.5 crashing silently

Tags: debugging, tomcat, weblogic12c

I have been facing this issue for a week now and I think I've reached dead end.
We are running reports remotely via Apache Tomcat and it's been crashing intermittently.
Requests are coming from Weblogic 12c.

There are no trace of the crash in any of the logs.

- Catalina.log
- Catalina.out
  -platform-deployment-local.log
  -.out

I saw some similar posts but I can't seem to find the hs_err file anywhere in the apache tomcat directory or in the var/log/messages.

These are the start-up parameters/configurations.

```
06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.437 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.37

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.444 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 12 2018 12:07:02 UTC

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.37.0

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.1.12-124.16.4.el7uek.x86_64

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /u01/jdk1.8.0_171/jre

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b11

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.446 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.446 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /u01/apachetomcat/config

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.446 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /u01/apachetomcat/config

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.447 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/u01/apachetomcat/config/conf/logging.properties

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.447 INFO [main] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.447 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2048m

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.447 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:PermSize=256m

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

06-Nov-2019 16:01:27.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:ErrorFile=/u01/apachetomcat/config/debug/tomcat_error%p.log
```

I have been starting Apache via `./catalina.sh jpda start` 
But still, no trace of the crash in the logs.
Are there more parameters/configurations I've missed or needed to add that will help me in my debugging?

Any inputs how I could debug further will be appreciated.

Comment: My guess it's the command line parameter:  -XX:ErrorFile=/u01/apachetomcat/config/debug/tomcat_error%pid   the % looks like a script issue?

Comment: @AlexC the crash was already happening way before I've added that extra parameter.

Comment: Delete all files in /var/log/tomcat8, then start the server and let it crash, check ALL log files in /var/log/tomcat8

Comment: Hi @AlexC, this directory is not existing. There's no tomcat8 directory under /var/log.

Comment: It seems to be in /u01/apachetomcat/config/debug/ ?  Wherever tomcat is writing the log files, clear them out and restart tomcat and see, sometimes it will write to an unexpected log file (like localhost log) before logging is initialized.  Also, try starting tomcat without your app, just by itself and see if that works.